# Finding multiple instances of ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

I believe I have multiple instances of ColdFusion running on my web server

- Services Control Panels lists two as running
- The one that powers the sites, does not have JVM setting listed
- task manager lists two jrun.exe 's

One of the instances response to port 80. I want to find the other one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what OS you're running, you could run portmap to find which port the second instance is using.

Comment: I am running windows 2008

Comment: Then you would want to use TCPView: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx